# How to have a different name for entries of a mongodb document in C#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

I'm trying to do CRUD operations on documents in **MongoDB** and **C#**. I would like to have fixed structured domain entities in C# with long meaningful property names but since the name of each property will be saved in MongoDB for each document, that's not a good idea. That's because property names will be redundantly saved in database and affect the total storage and performance.

The solution I can think of to overcome this problem, is to use different names for properties in C# than in MongoDB which means a mapping between them is needed. One elegant way of doing this is to incorporate C#'s attributes, something like this:

```
class Book
{
    [BsonProperty("n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonProperty("a")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

In this case documents would be saved in database like this:

```
{ n: "...", a: "..." }
```

I'm not sure if this is support in MongoDB's C# Driver or not!? I can not find it myself but I was hoping I'm looking in wrong places!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it at last.

```
class Book
{
    [BsonElement("n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("a")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

And this is [the page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/#element-name) with details.

Comment: dead link, 
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/